# How to detect whitespace in Character?

Tags: java

I am trying to do a simple lexical analyzer program for Mathematical Expression without validation which will read a line of Mathematical Expression and will break it into tokens according to the type of operator, digits, or identifiers that the program have read.

Everything looks fine and it returns the correct output according to the type of token but I was unable to detect **whitespace character**, even if I've used the method **Character.isWhitespace(char c)**

What I wanted to do is to simply ignore the whitespace and proceed to the next character...

Thank you for the help...

```
package Compilers;


import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyLexical{                           // Lexical processor of symbols
  public static void main(String[] args){
    char temp;
    int temp2,j=0;

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please input your mathematical expression.");
    String mathExpr= input.next();

    for(int i=0; i<mathExpr.length(); i++){
        temp= mathExpr.charAt(i);


        switch(temp){
            case '+': printLex(j,"plus"); break;
            case '-': printLex(j,"minus"); break;
            case '*': printLex(j,"multiply"); break;
            case '/': printLex(j,"divide"); break;
            case '=': printLex(j,"equal"); break;
            case '(': printLex(j,"lparen"); break;
            case ')': printLex(j,"rparen"); break;
            case '^': printLex(j,"exponent"); break;
            case '%': printLex(j,"modulus"); break;     
            case ',': printLex(j,"comma"); break; 
            case '.': printLex(j,"period"); break;   
            case ';': printLex(j,"semicolon"); break;
            case ':': temp2= mathExpr.charAt(i+1);
                      if(temp2=='='){
                          i++;
                          printLex(j,"becomes");
                      }
                      else{
                          printLex(j,"null");;
                      }
                      break;
            case '<': temp2= mathExpr.charAt(i+1); 
                      if(temp2=='>'){
                          i++;
                          printLex(j, "not equal");
                      }
                      else if(temp2=='='){
                          i++;
                          printLex(j, "less or equal than");
                      }
                      else {
                          printLex(j, "less than");
                      }
                      break;
             case '>': temp2= mathExpr.charAt(i+1); 
                      if(temp2=='='){
                          i++;
                          printLex(j, "greater or equal than");
                      }
                      else {
                          printLex(j, "greater than");
                      }
                      break;
             default :
                      if (Character.isDigit(temp)){
                          int num=0;
                          do{
                              num=10*num+Character.getNumericValue(temp);
                              if((i+1)!=mathExpr.length()){
                                if (Character.isDigit(mathExpr.charAt(i+1))){  
                                    temp=(mathExpr.charAt(i+1));
                                }
                                else
                                    break;
                              }
                              i++;
                          } while(i!=mathExpr.length() && Character.isDigit(temp));

                          printLex(j,String.valueOf(num));
                      }

                      else if (Character.isAlphabetic(temp)){
                          String entry="";
                          do{
                              entry+=String.valueOf(temp);
                              if((i+1)!=mathExpr.length()){
                                if (Character.isAlphabetic(mathExpr.charAt(i+1))){  
                                    temp=(mathExpr.charAt(i+1));
                                }
                                else
                                    break;
                              }
                              i++;
                          } while(i!=mathExpr.length() && Character.isAlphabetic(temp));

                          printLex(j,entry);
                      }

                      else if (Character.isWhitespace(temp)){
                          printLex(j,"space");
                      }

                     else {
                          System.out.println("Bad character");
                      }
                      break;  
        }

        j++;
    }
}

public static void printLex(int i, String temp){
    System.out.println("Token["+i+"]: "+temp);
  }
}//Lexical class
```

Comment: Here's [how to debug java code](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `Scanner` class. Instances of this class break up the input in tokens. The `next()` method will return the next token, and (by default) already ignores whitespace. Your `mathExpr` variable will thus never contain any whitespace characters.

You probably wanted to read an entire line of user input. For this you can use the `nextLine()` method of the `Scanner` class.

But since you want to do your own tokenizing, `Scanner` is probably overkill. You can also use a `BufferedReader` as follows:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(isr);
String mathExpr = r.readLine();
```

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for the reminder, if so is there a way to continue to read input even after whitespace? Because my program praticcaly stops reading other characters after the whitespace.

Comment: You can use the `Scanner.nextLine()` method. It returns an entire line of user input. I have edited the answer to add this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `continue` keyword to keep skip whitespaces:

```
switch (temp) {
    ...
    case ' ': continue;
}
```

Also, `input.next()` only reads one *token*, not a line. Perhaps you should be using `input.nextLine()`. Tokens are delimited by default with this whitespace regex: `\p{javaWhitespace}+`

Comment: @Insidious.C Did you trying using the `nextLine()` method as well?